# Powershell convert plain text to html

Tags: html, powershell

I have some text in a text file like this:

```
Unit 1: abc

Unit 2: abc
```

And the list goes on an on to Unit 3,4,..
Is there any way to convert the content of this file to .html format?
So that it would look like this (for example):

```
<p>Unit 1: abc</p>
<p></p>
<p>Unit 2: abc</p>
```

Googling hasn't really helped me on this one, thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Get-Content` cmdlet will read the file from disk, line-by-line, then all you need to do is:

1. Escape the input (in case it contains any HTML)
2. Surround each line with `<p>...</p>`

To escape the input, you can use `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode()`, and then construct the final string with the `-f` string format operator:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

Get-Content path\to\file.txt |ForEach-Object {
    '<p>{0}</p>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($_)
}
```

Comment: thanks, while it didn't work it for me (the [System.Web.HttpUtility] part gave an error), it gave me an idea how to do it using this
$file= $file|foreach {"<p>" + $_ + "</p>"}

Comment: @realjapaner84 In that case you can do `ForEach-Object { "<p>${_}</p>" }`, a bit simpler :) Out of curiosity, what kind of error message did you receive when invoking `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($_)`?

Comment: Says the Type [System.Web.HttpUtility] wasn't found